# Speed Up iTunes Sync on 192 kbps

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

I have something like 1450 songs on my iPhone 4S, and I have iTunes transcoding the files to 192 kbps as I don't have enough memory. The only problem is that the sync takes from 3 to 4 hours!

Is there any way I could speed it up?

My iPhone runs iOS 6.0 and my computer, Windows 8 Dev Preview.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the first sync, it has to transcode everything, which naturally takes a long time. If you check your Activity Monitor you'll probably see all cores at 100%. You could buy a computer with a faster CPU... or just be patient.

The first sync used to take about a day for me with 5000 songs on an old Core 2 Duo MacBook. At least you can stop the sync and it'll resume where it left off when you get back.

Comment: Just like to second this. My first sync, when choosing to transcode music, took a very long time. After this syncing takes very little time.